# Jquery loading content via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have an unordered list that will be used as a nav bar

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="content/index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/about.html" class="nav_bubble">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/projects.html" class="nav_bubble">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/tutorials.html" class="nav_bubble">Tutorials</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I have some javascript to load the content into a div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("div#navcontainer > ul > li > a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: e.currentTarget.href,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

All of that works, the question is, what happens when I load a page from my content folder that has a link in it? It sends your browser to the page instead of loading it into the div. How can I recursivly load all links into the content div instead of sending the user directly to them?

Comment: it is unclear to me . can you provide your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$("div#navcontainer > ul > li > a").click(function(e){
```

To:

```
$("div#navcontainer > ul > li > a, div#content a").live('click',function(e){
```

["Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: That did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did you try adding return false; to the end of your click listener?

Comment: Ah I completely misread your question. Long day. You'll need to add a live to the content div as well:  $("div#content a").live('click',function(e){ /*load ajax into content div */...

Comment: You could combine the listeners: $("div#navcontainer > ul > li > a, div#content a").live('click',function(e){ ...